# How to put a <script> inside a <script>?

Tags: javascript, html, discourse

JS noob here.
I'm not sure if this if I'm doing this correctly but I'm trying to run a script "within" another script.

```
<script type="text/discourse-plugin" version="0.8">
    api.decorateWidget('post:after', helper => {
        let post = helper.getModel();
        if (post.get('post_number') % 3 === 0) { // after every 3 posts
            return helper.rawHtml(`
<div class="lead_static_wrapper"><p>Label</p>
<div class="proper-ad-unit">
<div id="pr-ad-nr_main_1">


propertag.cmd.push(function() { proper_display('nr_main_1'); });


</div>
</div>
</div>
            `);
        }
    });
</script>
```

I need this part to run but it just shows as text when live, and doesn't seem to be running.

```
propertag.cmd.push(function() { proper_display('nr_main_1'); });
```

This doesn't seem to be the working:

```
<script type="text/discourse-plugin" version="0.8">
    api.decorateWidget('post:after', helper => {
        let post = helper.getModel();
        if (post.get('post_number') % 3 === 0) { // after every 3 posts
            return helper.rawHtml(`
<div class="lead_static_wrapper"><p>Label</p>
<div class="proper-ad-unit">
<div id="pr-ad-nr_main_1">


<script>propertag.cmd.push(function() { proper_display('nr_main_1'); });</script>


</div>
</div>
</div>
            `);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Is there a way to edit the JS structure so this works?
I'm trying to make this work for Discourse forums. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I'm not an expert, however script tags within script tags will not work. Is it possible to export the functions you need to a javascript file and import them as required?

Comment: I understand. I guess I was trying to show that that's what I'm trying to do, not necessarily the right way to do it.

Maybe there's a way to restructure the JS code so it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a backslash to escape the closing slash.

```
<script>propertag.cmd.push(function() { proper_display('nr_main_1'); });<\/script>
```